# Detect whenever another app attempts to record

Tags: java, android, audio-recording

I am writing an app that records audio continuously and waits for a known keyword, a bit like the Google Assistant which waits for "OK Google".

My issue is that while I am recording any other app that tries to record fails. I would like to stop my recording whenever another app on the system attempts to record and resume it when that app finishes.

Comment: Can't you get away with it using https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/custom-actions ?

Comment: No, as this is used for extra "OK Google" functionalities, whereas I need my own trigger (without going through Google Assistant or Google Now).

Comment: I suspected that. But what you're trying to achieve looks like a batterydrain, so I tried putting you on a user friendlier route (now is doing that already for you), but meh. Sorry couldn't help you mate :)